# how to convert the width of column of html table to the width of excel column in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have width of the column value as a percentage and I want to convert the same to excel width to set the width of the column. How do we do this in java, based on what the column width is calculated in excel.?

I use the following:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet(reportName); 
sheet.setColumnWidth((short)columnIterator, (short)6000);
```

In this method, the first argument is the column id and the second one is the width of the column. I want to set this width dynamically using the html width.

Example:

If the the column width in html is 10% then what is the equelant width in excel width.?
I want to set the column width of excel dynamically like setAutoColumnwidth().

UPDATE :

i found [this](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Excel-Column-Width-Unit-Converter-pixels-excel-column-width-units-td2301481.html), is this correct.

Regards,

Comment: 10% of what - without knowing the what there is no way of calculating the widht. Does the surrounding table have a fixed width?

Comment: @dngfng ??, supposing the Name column width is 10% in HTML, when i export the same table to excel i want to convert the 10% to excel column width like `sheet.setColumnWidth((short)columnIterator, (short)6000); if you in second argument it 6000 but i really don't know how to set this 6000 so what is the corresponding value for 10% ?.
`

Comment: @dngfng now it the question makes sense, I suppose.is it?

Comment: Well it states that 7px = 256 Excel width units - this still doesn't help you. Because you don't know how many pixels the column is wide. Its width is 10% of x, as long as you don't know x you can't calculate how many pixels/Excel width units the column is wide... does the surrounding table have a fixed width as in 1000px?

Comment: thanks a lot,it is nice explanation, still to explain my problem is , say Name column has the value of 'asdfasdfasdf asdf' i can find its length based on that how do i calculate excel width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29

Does this do what you want?

Comment: I think you have totally misunderstood, this is not what i am looking for,i have the value=10% based on this how to calculate the width of the excel column. this is what is my question. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: oh I think I finally understood you you have the value 10% in a field and you would like to ajust the width accordingly. <tr><td>10%</td></tr>

Comment: no, i want to convert that 10% to excel column width, it might come arround something like 2000 how to get exotically that value?

Comment: but this autoSizeColumn is not there

Comment: 10% of what, 10% of the standard column width, 10% of an A4 printed sheet?

Comment: what do you mean autoSizeColumn is not there, what version are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17125/discussion-between-anto-and-dngfng)